# Dependent Dropdown not working inside while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    echo "<select name = error_type id='error_type$rowIndex' name='error_type$rowIndex' class='error_type'>
    <option value= >Select Type</option>
      <option value=Category1>Category1</option>
      <option value=Category2>Category2</option>
      </select>
    </td><td>
   <select disabled=disabled id='remarks$rowIndex' name='remarks$rowIndex' class='remarks'>
    <option value= >Select Subtype </option>
    <option rel='Category1' value='Subcategory1.1'>Subcategory1.1</option>
    <option rel='Category1' value='Subcategory1.2'>Subcategory1.2</option>
    <option rel='Category1' value='Subcategory1.3'>Subcategory1.3</option>
    <option rel='Category2' value='Subcategory2.1'>Subcategory2.1</option>
    <option rel='Category2' value='Subcategory2.2'>Subcategory2.2</option>
    <option rel='Category2' value='Subcategory2.3'>Subcategory2.3</option>                      
    </select>";
```

I have a php table which outputs 'n' number of rows,each row with 2 dropdowns. The above section of code works only for the first row of the Php table, but when the next row is changed, the first row's subcategory also changes.How do i make individual rows act independently.

the js is,

```
    $(function(){

    var $error_type = $(".error_type"),
        $remarks = $(".remarks");

    $error_type.on("change",function(){
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        $remarks.find("option").attr("style","");
        $remarks.val("");
        if(!_rel) return $remarks.prop("disabled",true);
        $remarks.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
        $remarks.prop("disabled",false);
    });

});
```

The cs is,

```
.remarks option{
    display:none;
}

.remarks option.label{
    display:block;
}
```

--EDIT--

```
$(function(){

    var $error_type = $(".error_type"),
        $remarks = $(".remarks");

    $error_type.on("change",function(){
        var $remarks = $(this).closest("tr").find(".remarks");
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        $remarks.find("option").attr("style","");
        $remarks.val("");
        if(!_rel) return $remarks.prop("disabled",true);
        $remarks.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
        $remarks.prop("disabled",false);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to resolve to *all* matching elements:

```
$remarks = $(".remarks");
```

You're doing that once when the page loads and then always operating on *all* of those elements.  Instead, remove that line completely and find the specific element you're looking for when the event happens, using the source of the event as a starting point.

Perhaps something like this:

```
$error_type.on("change", function(){
    var $remarks = $(this).closest("tr").find(".remarks");
    // the rest of your handler code
});
```

The idea is that when the `change` event happens, you start from `this` (which is the element that triggered the event), traverse the DOM to a common parent element (given your HTML that's likely a `<tr>`), then finds the specific target `.remarks` element(s) contained specifically within that parent.

Comment: `$(function(){
    
    var $error_type = $(".error_type"),
        //$remarks = $(".remarks");
    
    $error_type.on("change",function(){
        var $remarks = $(this).closest("tr").find(".remarks");
  var _rel = $(this).val();
        $remarks.find("option").attr("style","");
        $remarks.val("");
        if(!_rel) return $remarks.prop("disabled",true);
        $remarks.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
        $remarks.prop("disabled",false);
    });
    
});`

Comment: @SriRam: (1) Code should go in the question, not in comments, for obvious readability reasons. (2) Define "doesn't work". What does it do? In what way does it fail? Include a sample of the HTML you're using so we can see what the JavaScript code is actually operating on.

Comment: Sorry about that david. I'm new to this place and just learning to use this website. Doesn't work -- > It works perfectly fine for the first row.When you change the category in the second row,the selected subcategory in the first row gets changed too.and this occurs in all the subsequent rows

Comment: @SriRam: Provide a more complete example in the question.  Currently your HTML doesn't *have* more than one row.  Forget the PHP parts, just show the resulting HTML itself.

Comment: Was trying out exactly as you said. Now it works great! thanks David!

Comment: Thanks for your help david, but i have one more small issue. When i select category1, only the respective subtypes show up in the 2nd dropdown but i'm still able to select an option from category2 by typing in the letters, say for example i select category1 and hit tab and type 2.2 it shows up in the 2nd dropdown. any idea why this is happening. Is there a way to literally lock the 2nd dropdown options respective to the 1st dropdown options