# Non relational <option> can still be selected using shortcut keys in dependent dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select id='type$rowIndex' name='type$rowIndex' class='type'>
<option selected disabled>Select Type</option>
<option value=Category1>Category1</option>
<option value=Category2>Category2</option>
</option>
<select disabled=disabled id='remarks$rowIndex' name='remarks$rowIndex' class='remarks'>
<option value= >Select remakrs</option>
<option rel='Category1' value='a'>a</option>
<option rel='Category1' value='b'>b</option>
<option rel='Category1' value='c'>c</option>
<option rel='Category2' value='d'>d</option>
<option rel='Category2' value='e'>e</option>
<option rel='Category2' value='f'>f</option>
</select>
```

The Jquery is,

```
$(function(){

    var $type = $(".type"),
        $remarks = $(".remarks");

    $type.on("change",function(){
        var $remarks = $(this).closest("tr").find(".remarks");
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        $remarks.find("option").attr("style","");
        $remarks.val("");
        if(!_rel) return $remarks.prop("disabled",true);
        $remarks.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
        $remarks.prop("disabled",false);
    });

});
```

The CS is

```
.remarks option{
    display:none;
}

.remarks option.label{
    display:block;
}
```

This works perfectly fine according to my requirement inside a php while loop where 'n' number of rows would be formed with 2 dropdown each.I'm able to see only a, b and c in the seconddropdown when category1 is selected,but when i select category1 and hit tab and type 'd' or 'e' or 'f' it shows up in the second dropdown.Why is this happening. Do i have any options to literally 'lock' the options(remarks) with their corresponding main category.

Comment: Copying your markup into a fiddle or plunkr I cannot replicate your issue. Any disabled option is disabled and cannot be selected through keying in letters, using arrow keys or direct selection.

Comment: @Fran thanks for your effors please find my previous question to get more clarity on the issue [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372958/dependent-dropdown-not-working-inside-while-loop]